which database is suitable
I have a postgres as main database. Couple tables are huge, they store approximately 5 million rows. So my query usually contains couple joins which are super expensive, so I decided to denormalize the tables, but still adding new column is huge headache. Businesses want us to add new parameters for filtering the data. Each new parameter is either new join or new fields in the database. I am searching for best database for that scenarios.
I am thinking about noSQL database, like MongoDB. But have concerns about its ability to fast data retrieval, and ability to add new filter parameters as quick as possible. And as far as I know indexing in mongo is a headache. So maybe you can offer better solution

Both? You don't need to choose one or the other. Use the best one for each use case. You'll need to replicate data regularly, though.

Hi - please be aware that asking for product recommendations is off topic for this forum and will often result in your question being closed. Given that, having 5M rows in a table is not huge by any modern standards but is tiny and any properly set up DBMS should be able to handle it with no issues. I suggest that you update your question with the DDL for the tables, provide an example query that is causing problems and add the EXPLAIN PLAN for that query - then someone should be able to help you

5 millions records is not a huge. Please provide DDL for involved tables, sample query and EXPLAIN PLAN

If a new parameter leads to a new join, this makes me wonder if you are using an [tag:entity-attribute-value] table. These are indeed hard to optimize, regardless of which brand of SQL database you use.
